# Jenkins cucumber reports plugin buildStaus has no affect

Tags: jenkins, cucumber, jenkins-pipeline, cucumber-jvm

I coudn't get the  build status change to UNSTABLE in jenkins. seems cucumber buildStatus has no affect ?
or it would be helpful to know what i am doing wrong ?

```
post {
    always {
        cucumber buildStatus: 'UNSTABLE',
                failedFeaturesNumber: 1,
                failedScenariosNumber: 1,
                skippedStepsNumber: 1,
                failedStepsNumber: 1,
                fileIncludePattern: '**/*cucumber-report.json',
                trendsLimit: 10
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Do you have some reports marked failed or unstable? Even if you have, number of steps/features/scenarios must be above one, because you declared things like `failedFeaturesNumber: 1`
[Documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/cucumber-reports/) claims that

> failedFeaturesNumber (optional)
>   Maximum number of failed features above which build result is triggered. Provide value -1 if the rule should be skipped.

Comment: [CucumberReport] Found 26 failed steps, while expected at most 1
 [CucumberReport] Build status is changed to UNSTABLE  ,                                          
     this is my pipeline build output shows this. but jenkins build still shows as failed.

Comment: found the root cause, sh "command" returning exit 1 ,when tests are failed. Jenkins looking at that exit code  and status is Failed .   ignored the shell failure by  sh "command || true"  . Now cucumber buildStatus working as expected .!

Comment: @chandu but are you sure that cucumber reports plugin is able to always catch the error if shell command fails? I didn't find any information how it is going in case of failure.

Comment: i am not sure if i understand your question correctly, In jenkins build step I have shell mvn cmd to run cucumber tests., In post build , i always run cucumber reports.    If this shell cmd ( or tests )fails, the jenkins build status is set to failed. eventhough i run cucumber report step later, cucumber doesn't change /affect the buildStatus. to UNSTABLE, even  if the conditions met.  So i came up with sh "command || true"  it basically doesn't return exit 1, when shell (tests) fail, no  build status chnage by Shell.  only then Cumcumber is able change the buildStatus.

Comment: @chandu I have similar issue, could you give me more tips? I tried your solution, like append '|| true' to the end of 'sh command' but it doesn't seem to work. build status still seem to change by the shell? when I check the jenkins log, I cannot find the '|| true ' appended in mvn command. Thanks.

Comment: in my pipeline build logs  i can see its printed as 2020-08-24 05:02:31 + true
2020-08-24 05:02:31 [Pipeline] }.  after mvn command, it think  this true prints only when the mvn command fails. thus ignores the shell changing the  build status to fail. then cucumber is able to change the build status.,